# MYSQL SUM, value has to change on condition

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have a "CONTRACTS" table in which the user can select whether a Contract is "ANUAL" or "MONTHLY" *(working on MariaDB/phpmyadmin)*

The data is stored in the following manner:

| CONTRACT | PERIOD | CICLE | SALE PRICE | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | YEARLY | 12000 | CAT1 |
| 002 | 1 | MONTHLY | 1000 | CAT2 |

I want to make a report that tells me the SUM of monthly contracts by CATEGORY

RIGHT NOW, THIS QUERY BELOW WORKS but its useless, since its doing SUM of "yearly" contracts along with monthly contracts

```sql
SELECT SUM(contracts.salesprice), `categories`.*
        FROM `contracts` 
        LEFT JOIN `categories` ON `contratos`.`cat_id` = `categories`.`id_cat`
     GROUP BY categorias.descripcion_cat;1
```

I'm a newbie and so far I was fine with INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE;
I tried reading all documentation about CASE or IF, but I cant figure how to tell mysql to SUM based AND calculate on conditions

when CICLE = YEARLY then SALEPRICE /12 (to get the monthly value)

Comment: You should first filter all rows that have the CICLE = 'MONTHLY', then apply join and aggregation. Have you tried using `WHERE` clauses? @Kaoru

Comment: thanks for the answere but filtering where CICLE monthly doesnt help, because I would leftt out of the totals the CICLE YEARLY value, 
if I want a monthly average per category that wouldnt work.
Also if i later want to do a yearly average per category I would need to multiply the SalePrice *12 When Cicle = MONTHLY

Comment: The `SELECT` statement doesn't change the values inside your table. If you later want to do a yearly average per category, you can directly query the same table by filtering on `CICLE = 'YEARLY'`. You can generate these as two views instead of creating new tables (or leaving them as `SELECT` queries).

Comment: yes, I understand I could make 2 querys, one to get Monthly SUM results, and one to get YEARLY results then I just divide /12 to get the monthly average of yearly contracts, and then maybe do something in PHP with the results
However in documentation and some examples I've seen about SUM you can make querys based on conditions and get the results directly in Mysql. 
But that's more advanced and beyond what I can do with the provided documentation/examples.

Comment: Share your attempts and current outputs, maybe they need just some little quick fixes. @Kaoru

Answer (score 0):

You were on the correct track with `CASE`.

The following code snippet will convert your yearly sales prices into monthly:

```sql
SUM(
  CASE 
    WHEN contracts.cicle = 'YEARLY' THEN (contracts.salesprice / 12) 
    WHEN contracts.cicle = 'MONTHLY' THEN contracts.salesprice
    ELSE 0 
  END
)
```

To use it in your query, simply replace your `SUM(...)` with that one.

To explain what it is doing, the `CASE` statement has several `WHEN` conditions. It uses the value of the first one that is true, if none are true, it will use the `ELSE` value (which you can change if you don't like 0). All of those resulting values are then summed up with `SUM`.

The benefit of `CASE` over `IF` is that `CASE` can be expanded as needed if you need more calculations for bi-annual, quarter, etc.